# I went to jog / I went for a jog / I went jogging

Tags: grammaticality

Sorry if this is a stupid question to ask here, but I don't have much formal knowledge of grammar.

I just want to know if "I went to jog" is grammatical, and if so, are there any differences between "I went to jog", "I went for a jog", and "I went jogging"?

Comment: You might find ELL a more suitable site for your needs. For example I recently answered a similar (not identical) [question](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/7103/1694) to yours..

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing ungrammatical about "I went to jog", though it is not as colloquial as the other two. They all mean essentially the same thing. If you wanted to make a fine distinction, you could say that "a jog" is for some (understood) distance or time, while "jogging" is just the idea of jogging without any specific time/distance.

Answer (score 2):

All three are perfectly grammatical. Although the grammatical function the word *jog* / *jogging* is different in each case, they all have essentially the same meaning.

- *I went to jog* - '*to jog*' is an [infinitive phrase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitive).
- *I went for a jog* - '*for a jog*' is a [prepositional phrase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adpositional_phrase#Prepositional_phrases).
- *I went jogging* - '*jogging*' is a [gerund](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerund).

A speaker will probably favor one construction over the others, depending on the speaker's native dialect.

Comment: To my native ear, "I went for a jog" and "I went jogging" are natural constructions.  "I went to jog" is the odd one out. It is more like "Q.  Why did you go to the park?  A.  I went to jog."  If I asked somebody "Hey, what did you do this afternoon?" and they said "I went jogging" or "I went for a jog" I might leave it at that.  If they said "I went to jog" however, I would most probably ask "Oh?  Where did you go?" because it would sound like they went somewhere in particular for the purpose of jogging upon arrival.

Comment: Thanks! If you have time, can you explain more on how a speaker's native dialect can influence preference for one of those phrases?

Comment: _I went to jog_ has two senses for me. One is the purpose infinitive sense that mikeY mentions; the other is an idiom for an aborted action: _I went to jog, but someone had stolen my jockstrap_.